# Fastest way to change image pixels before rendering on an HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a (largish) HTML5 canvas. Its rendering a pictures from a file, using `context.drawImage()` and this is quite fast. (Note that there are more than one picture on the same canvas).

Now I need to perform some manipulations to the pixels on the canvas, basically I need to perform Alpha Blending which darkens certain areas of the picture. So instead I used this approach.

```
 //create an invisible canvas so that we don't do the actual rendering of the image
 var invisibleCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 invisibleCanvas.width = myWidth;
 invisibleCanvas.height = myHeight;

 var invContext = invisibleCanvas.getContext('2d');
 invContext.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, invisibleCanvas.width, invisibleCanvas.height);
 var imageData = invContext.getImageData(0, 0, invisibleCanvas.width, invisibleCanvas.height)
 var pixelComponents = imageData.data;

 var dkBlendingAmount = 0.5;
 for (var i = 0; i < pixelComponents.length; i += 4)
 {
    //there are a few extra checks here to see if we should do the blending or not

    pixelComponents[i] = pixelComponents[i] * dkBlendingAmount;
    pixelComponents[i+1] = pixelComponents[i+1] * dkBlendingAmount;
    pixelComponents[i+2] = pixelComponents[i+2] * dkBlendingAmount;
 }

 //this is the real place where I want it
 context.putImageData(imageData, xOffset, yOffset);
```

Is there a way to make this faster? Is there a way to get the image data directly from my `imageObj` rather than having to put it on a canvas, get the data, convert it and put it on another canvas?

Comment: Canvas is the only simple way grabbing pixel data...and the next best way is writing some image decoders (ouch!). Are these images known beforehand? Perhaps you could precalc the blended image. If you don't know the blending composition ahead of time you could at least pre-fetch the pixel data.

Comment: Thanks. The performance on normal desktop browsers is OK. But the performance on iPad takes a couple of seconds which is annoying. The unblended pixel data is not the issue really. Its images I load on the fly but once they're cached they're pretty much ok. Its this blending (which I can't do beforehand because it depends on what the user does) that is the problem.